# Rsyslog - RainerScript control structures not working

Tags: rsyslog

I am trying to separate rsyslog 8.24 logs from xCAT based on the presence of the string "nagios".

I have following conf file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/config_file.conf` with the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file contianing `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`

```
template(name="xCATTraditionalFormat0" type="string" string="%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %syslogseverity-text:::uppercase% %msg:::drop-last-lf%\n")

#Separate messages based on presence of nagios string

if ($programname == "xcat") and ($msg contains "nagios") then { 
   action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/xcat/nagios.log" template="xCATTraditionalFormat0") 
   stop 
} else if ($programname == "xcat") then { 
   action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/xcat/cluster.log" template="xCATTraditionalFormat0")
   stop     
}
```

However, both log files are empty. Curiously, if I add one more `{` to the end of this config file logs are registered. Unfortunately, that collides with rest of rest of config files so I am looking for a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Rsyslog does not support `else if` blocks. [Conditional Expressions](https://rsyslog-mm.readthedocs.io/en/v7.4_stable/config/conditionals.html#conditional-expressions) generally follow the structure:

```
if <expression> then <block>
if <expression> then <block> else <block>
```

Edit your `config_file.conf` and structure it as:

```
if ($programname == "xcat") {
    if ($msg contains "nagios") then {
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/xcat/nagios.log" template="xCATTraditionalFormat0")
    } else {
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/xcat/cluster.log" template="xCATTraditionalFormat0")
    }
    stop
}
```